# SQL specific WHERE clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new at SQL and am trying to organize some baseball data with specific restrictions.

I'm given data of the day, inning, pitcher who is pitching, and whether it is the top or bottom of the inning.

Is there a way to query the system efficiently where I will get back data only when there is a singular pitcher for an inning?

```
|-----------------------------------|
| day | inning | pitcher| top_bottom|
|  1       1        AE1      top    |
|  1       1        AE1      top    |
|  1       1        AE1      top    |
|  1       2        AE1      top    |
|  1       2        AE1      top    |
|  1       2        AE2      top    |
|-----------------------------------|
```

The result would be the first 3 rows, since in each event the pitcher was AE1, whereas I would not get the bottom three rows, since both pitchers AE1 and AE2 pitched in said inning.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which will likely prove problematic in due course.

Comment: Are you running mysql, or bigquery? These are two different database products, please tag only the relevant one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your data by each `inning` and take only those groups having only one distinct pitcher:

```
select inning, max(pitcher) as pitcher
from your_table
where day = 1
group by inning
having count(distinct pitcher) = 1
```

If you need the complete record and not just the 2 columns then you can do:

```
select * 
from your_table
where inning in 
(
  select inning
  from your_table
  where day = 1
  group by inning
  having count(distinct pitcher) = 1
)
```

Comment: The query is over a large database and the result is empty. Is there a way to specify the distinction only on the certain day rather than over the entire database. So if the pitcher pitches on one day and then a week later it won't cause a problem.

Comment: I added `where day = 1` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,inning INT NOT NULL
,pitcher CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,'AE1'),
(2,1,'AE1'),
(3,1,'AE1'),
(4,2,'AE1'),
(5,2,'AE1'),
(6,2,'AE2');

SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.inning = x.inning 
            AND y.pitcher <> x.pitcher 
            AND y.id <> x.id 
          WHERE y.id IS NULL;
+----+--------+---------+
| id | inning | pitcher |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 | AE1     |
|  2 |      1 | AE1     |
|  3 |      1 | AE1     |
+----+--------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, you can use:

```
select as value any(t)
from t
group by t.inning
having min(pitcher) = max(pitcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(singular_pitcher)
FROM (
  SELECT *, 1 = COUNT(DISTINCT pitcher) OVER(PARTITION BY day, inning) singular_pitcher
  FROM `project.dataset.table`  t
)
WHERE singular_pitcher
```